# Draw circle only, not ellipse

Tags: java

I have the below code that draws an ellipse when the user drags the mouse, however I only want a circle to be drawn and not an ellipse also.

I've tried a few things but haven't quite got it to work, from what I understand it places the circle inside a rectangle, so if I can lock that so it places it inside a square then I should get what I want? The code may not be the most efficient, I'm just trying to write this for a project I'm working, to be clear this is not school homework or anything. If I can get at least this circle aspect of the code working it will save me a lot of time in my project

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DrawingBoardWithMatrix extends JFrame {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      DrawingBoardWithMatrix drawingBoardWithMatrix = new DrawingBoardWithMatrix();
  }

  public DrawingBoardWithMatrix() {
    this.setSize(600, 600);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.add(new PaintSurface(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.setVisible(true);
  }

  private class PaintSurface extends JComponent {
    ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();

    Point startDrag, endDrag;

    public PaintSurface() {
      this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
          startDrag = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
          endDrag = startDrag;
          repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
          Shape r = makeCircle(startDrag.x, startDrag.y, e.getX(), e.getY());
          shapes.add(r);
          startDrag = null;
          endDrag = null;
          repaint();
        }

      });

      this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
          endDrag = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
          repaint();
        }
      });
    }
    private void paintBackground(Graphics2D g2){
      g2.setPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
      for (int i = 0; i < getSize().width; i += 10) {
        Shape line = new Line2D.Float(i, 0, i, getSize().height);
        g2.draw(line);
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < getSize().height; i += 10) {
        Shape line = new Line2D.Float(0, i, getSize().width, i);
        g2.draw(line);
      }


    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      paintBackground(g2);



      g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
      g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.50f));

      for (Shape s : shapes) {
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2.draw(s);
       // g2.setPaint(colors[(colorIndex++) % 6]);
       // g2.fill(s);
      }

      if (startDrag != null && endDrag != null) {
        g2.setPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        Shape r = makeCircle(startDrag.x, startDrag.y, endDrag.x, endDrag.y);
        g2.draw(r);
      }
    }

    private Ellipse2D.Float makeCircle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
      return new Ellipse2D.Float(Math.min(x1, x2), Math.min(y1, y2), Math.abs(x1 - x2), Math.abs(y1 - y2));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `makeCircle()` draws an ellipse with width `Math.abs(x1 - x2)` and height `Math.abs(y1 - y2)`. If you want to draw a circle, the width and height must be equal. There are several ways to accomplish this:

- Use `Math.abs(x1 - x2)` for both width and height
- Use `Math.abs(y1 - y2)` for both width and height
- Decide between the two based on the mouse position

However, I am very concerned about your statement "I just don't have the time right now to learn Java properly" - this *will* come back to bite you. If you have any intention of having programming as a serious hobby or potentially a job down the line, you *must* expend a lot of effort to properly understand what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks Aasmund. I knew the two must be equal just wasn't quite sure how to achieve this. Using math.abs(x1 - x2) seems to work fine, so simple! As for your concerns, I'm fully aware I need to study properly from the beginning. I understand the theory of OOP etc, just need to familiarize myself with Java - but like I said, this is purely to save me doing some stuff by hand in a project I'm working on, this is the only code involved. Thanks again for the help